# Prevent rake task dependency from loading Rails twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, factory-bot, rake-task

Following the example at http://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-your-factories-first
the line `task spec: :factory_specs` in the Rakefile tells rake to execute "factory_specs" task before "spec" task.

My issue is that `rake spec` loads the Rails environment twice, one to execute factory_specs task and then another to execute spec task.

How do I prevent my rake command from loading Rails twice?

My stack:

- Ruby 1.9.3p484
- Rails 3.2.13

Comment: Rake already optimises this. (i.e if you are calling two tasks asks and both have the same dependency, then it is invoked only once). Infact, in a call chain, same task will never be executed more than once

Comment: Not with my stack and scenario. It took about 30 seconds to load Rails each time before a task is run, while the tasks themselves take only 2 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest version of FactoryGirl, you can use `FactoryGirl.lint` instead of explicitly testing your factories in a separate rake task. Just update to the latest version and add this to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.lint
  end
end
```

More info is in the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories).

Comment: best answer so far, thanks! FactoryGirl just added this feature 14 days ago...just in time.